# Search while typing and passing info into to multiple HTML form elements

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I've managed to cut and past my way this far !

I have a customer database.  I have this nice HTML form to fill out.  When I click submit, it populates a fillable PDF on the server.

When you start typing the name, it shows all the results, and you can click on one of them, and it populates the NAME part of the HTML field.  but only the name.  I want it to populate all the HTML elements. (maybe not the check box).

Here is my HTML form called search.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Deer Processing</title>
   <!-- jQuery library is required. -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Include our script file. -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
   <!-- Include the CSS file. -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Search box. 
   <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search" /> -->
   
   
  <div id="registration-form">
  <div class='fieldset'>
  <legend>Deer Processing Form</legend>
    <form action="formFiller.php" method="post">
      <div class='row'>
        <label for="Name_textbox"></label>
        <input type="text" id="search" name="Name_textbox" placeholder="Name">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="Address_textbox"></label>
        <input type="text" id="address" name="Address_textbox" placeholder="Address">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="CityState_textbox"></label>
        <input type="text" name="CityState" placeholder="City, State">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="Zip_textbox"></label>
        <input type="text" name="Zip_textbox" placeholder="Zip Code">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="CellPhone_textbox"></label>
        <input type="text" name="CellPhone_textbox" placeholder="Cell Phone">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox_1_checkbox">
        <label for="Checkbox_1_checkbox">Receive Text Message</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="SecondaryPhone_textbox"></label>
        <input type="text" name="SecondaryPhone_textbox" placeholder="Mandatory Phone">
      </div>
      

      <input type="submit">
    <div id="display"></div>
    </form>
    </div></div>
   
   
   
   <br>
   <b>Example: </b><i>Emily Anderson, Liam Johnson, Sophia Martinez, Ethan Thompson, Olivia Davis</i>
   <br />
   <!-- Suggestions will be displayed in the following div. -->
   <div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my AJAX.PHP file.

```
<?php
// Include the database configuration file.
include "db.php";
// Retrieve the value of the "search" variable from "script.js".
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
   // Assign the search box value to the $Name variable.
   $Name = $_POST['search'];
   // Define the search query.
   $Query = "SELECT Name, Address, CityState FROM customers WHERE Name LIKE '%$Name%' LIMIT 50";
   // Execute the query.
   $ExecQuery = MySQLi_query($con, $Query);
   // Create an unordered list to display the results.
   echo '
<ul>
   ';
   // Fetch the results from the database.
   while ($Result = MySQLi_fetch_array($ExecQuery)) {
       ?>
   <!-- Create list items.
        Call the JavaScript function named "fill" found in "script.js".
        Pass the fetched result as a parameter. -->
   <li onclick='fill("<?php echo $Result['Name']; ?>")'>
   <a>
   <!-- Display the searched result in the search box of "search.php". -->
       <?php echo $Result[0]; ?><?php echo", "; ?>
       <?php echo $Result[1]; ?><?php echo", "; ?>
       <?php echo $Result[2]; ?>
   </li></a>
   <!-- The following PHP code is only for closing parentheses. Do not be confused. -->
   <?php
}}
?>
</ul>
```

Here is my script.js file.

```
// Retrieve the value from "ajax.php".
function fill(Value) {
   // Assign the value to the "search" div in "search.php".
   $('#search').val(Value);
   // Hide the "display" div in "search.php".
   $('#display').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   // When a key is pressed in the "Search box" of "search.php", this function will be called.
   $("#search").keyup(function() {
       // Assign the search box value to a JavaScript variable named "name".
       var name = $('#search').val();
       // Validate if "name" is empty.
       if (name == "") {
           // Assign an empty value to the "display" div in "search.php".
           $("#display").html("");
       }
       // If the name is not empty.
       else {
           // Initiate an AJAX request.
           $.ajax({
               // Set the AJAX type as "POST".
               type: "POST",
               // Send data to "ajax.php".
               url: "ajax.php",
               // Pass the value of "name" into the "search" variable.
               data: {
                   search: name
               },
               // If a result is found, this function will be called.
               success: function(html) {
                   // Assign the result to the "display" div in "search.php".
                   $("#display").html(html).show();
               }
           });
       }
   });
});
```

[as you type John it finds all johns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMpuL.png)
[but it only passes his name to the form, no his address and city/state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG1Oj.png)

I would like after you click the search result you like, for it to populate the address and city state.  (i also have two phones and other info too, but one thing at a time).

Comment: Hint: simply amend the fill JS function to auto-fill the other data fields

Comment: i feel i'm close but have been at it for a bit now.

<li onclick='fill("<?php echo $Result['Name']; ?>")'>

I cant figure out how to get that part to be an array once it gets over to the JS file at this spot

   $('#search').val(Value);

Comment: Your code is open for [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Answer (score 0):

To tackle your problem, you may return the data (Name, Address, CityState) thru ajax with proper delimiters, then process the ajax return onchange of the select box)

Hence,

(1) Please add ID to your CityState input box, so change

```
<input type="text" name="CityState" placeholder="City, State">
```

to

```
<input type="text" id="CityState" name="CityState" placeholder="City, State">
```

(2) Then, amend your ajax.php from

```
 echo '
<ul>
   ';
   // Fetch the results from the database.
   while ($Result = MySQLi_fetch_array($ExecQuery)) {
       ?>
   <!-- Create list items.
        Call the JavaScript function named "fill" found in "script.js".
        Pass the fetched result as a parameter. -->
   <li onclick='fill("<?php echo $Result['Name']; ?>")'>
   <a>
   <!-- Display the searched result in the search box of "search.php". -->
       <?php echo $Result[0]; ?><?php echo", "; ?>
       <?php echo $Result[1]; ?><?php echo", "; ?>
       <?php echo $Result[2]; ?>
   </li></a>
   <!-- The following PHP code is only for closing parentheses. Do not be confused. -->
  <?php
}}
?>
</ul>
```

to

```
 echo '<select id=ajaxreturn onchange="javascript:fill();">
<option value="">Please select';

while ($Result = MySQLi_fetch_array($ExecQuery)) { ?>

<option value="<?php echo $Result[0]; ?><?php echo"||"; ?><?php echo $Result[1]; ?><?php echo"||"; ?><?php echo $Result[2]; ?>" >

       <?php echo $Result[0]; ?><?php echo", "; ?>
       <?php echo $Result[1]; ?><?php echo", "; ?>
       <?php echo $Result[2]; ?>

   </option>
  <?php
}}
?>
</select>
```

(3) Finally, amend your fill JS function to:

```
function fill() {

var strUser = document.getElementById("ajaxreturn").value;

 if (strUser!="") {
    const myArray = strUser.split("||");
    $('#search').val(myArray[0]);
    $('#address').val(myArray[1]);
    $('#CityState').val(myArray[2]);
    $('#display').hide();
 }
}
```